# Qt Creator загружает всю ОЗУ (8 ГБ)

Tags: qt, gui, qt5, qt-designer, qtcreator

При открытии редактора форм загрузка ОЗУ вырастает до 100%, и, в лучшем случае, программа вылетает, в худшем - нужно отключать от питания компьютер.
Та же ситуация и с Qt designer. Везде, где есть редактор форм, - 100% загрузка ОЗУ.
В Интернете ничего не нашел.

Windows 10, Qt 6.3.1, Qt Creator 7.0.2 (Community)

Comment: Детали добавьте, какая ОС, версия Qt...

Answer (score 1):

У меня такое случается, когда запущено приложение в Qt Creator'e. Как правило, связано с утечкой памяти.
Но если дело в QtCreator'e - Вы можете запустить исходный код QtCreator'а под отладкой, например, в другом QtCreator'e.
Я так делаю, и порой нахожу ошибки.
Но под Ubuntu 20.04 я не смог воспроизвести этот баг. Я собрал исходный код версии 7.0.2, открыл редактор форм - все работает нормально.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]