# Qt Creator Редактор форм загружает всю ОЗУ

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-designer, qtcreator

На прикрепленном видео всё продемонстрировано: при запуске редактора форм в Qt Creator загрузка памяти подскакивает до 100%. Если успеть закрыть программу, то не придется отключать ПК от питания.
Такая же ситуация если запускать редактор форм с помощью Visual Studio 2019.
Месяц назад все работало, на протяжении месяца ничего не устанавливал.
Win 10 Home, QT 6.3.1, QtCreator 7.0.2
[Видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KE-pGowM8tk)

Comment: дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1427857/qt-creator-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%8e-%d0%9e%d0%97%d0%a3-8-%d0%93%d0%91

Comment: Я уже месяц пытаюсь исправить проблему, не хочу винду сносить

Answer (score 1):

Установите версию Qt 5, возможно проблема с новой версией